# Redis "evicted_keys" purpose

Tags: redis

While executing the info command in `redis-cli`, all the information related to that server is listed. What is the purpose of "evicted_keys"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Redis can be configured to automatically purge keys as necessary. If so configured, redis will only use a maximum amount of memory, and if it nears the limit, remove keys per some criteria. See [Redis as an LRU cache](http://antirez.com/post/redis-as-LRU-cache.html) by antirez.

It can be configured to only remove keys that have an expiry time, or all keys. It can remove keys soon to be expired, last recently used keys, or random keys.

`evicted_keys` in the `info` is the number of keys that have been evicted (removed).